# Decoding JWT token on app route using express-jwt with RS256 encryption throws UnAuthorized Error

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, express-jwt

I am using Keycloak for authentication and using it's middleware I have attatch a token to my request. I a trying to write an api route that retrieves user data using that token however, I get the following error:

```
UnauthorizedError: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line
```

Currently I am accessing the user data on the '/protected/' route

```
app.get('/protected', jwt({
  secret: Buffer.from(process.env.TOKEN_SECRET as string), 
  algorithms: ['RS256'],
  requestProperty: 'auth',
  getToken: (req: any) => {
    const token = req?.kauth?.grant?.access_token;
    if (token) {
      console.log(token.token.toString())
      return token.token.toString();
    } 
    return null;
  }
}), (req: any, res: any) => {
  return res.json(req.auth)
});
```

I am getting my public key from keycloak console - but I still get that error.

** EDIT **

After adding the first and last line to the secret:

```
`-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\r\n${Buffer.from(process.env.TOKEN_SECRET as string)}\r\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`
```

I am now getting a new error:

```
UnauthorizedError: No authorization token was found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keycloak doesn't return the first and last lines basically the header and footer. So you need to add it yourself.

```
const publicKey = `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\r\n${public_key}\r\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`
```

and use this in the express-jwt

Comment: I have added this but now I am getting a new error :
`UnauthorizedError: No authorization token was found` What could cause this issue?

Comment: I mean that is your business logic problem or something, the scope of this question i believe is solved. Because you didn't know that you needed to add the header and footer now you do. 
  
For the current problem use the public key in `jwt.io` to check if you can validate the jwt.